# Вызов функции isinf на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

Подскажите пожалуйста, как написать на ассемблере компилятора GCC вызов функции isinf().

В целом моя задача, написать проверку числа типа float на то, inf ли оно или нет.

Примечание: isinf() - это по сути макрос, а не функция

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если он макрос, то вы его ни как не вызовете. Что бы что то вызвать это что то должно быть уже скомпилировано в набор инструкций процессора. А макрос C, он просто текст для компилятора. Так что лучше написать свою функцию, посмотрите систему команд с плавающей точкой, что то мне подсказывает что там вся проверка займет несколько инструкций

Comment: Как вариант, сделайте программу на C, в которой с помощью этого макроса что либо проверяете, потом попросите GCC сделать из этого ассемблерный код и посмотрите, что именно он сделал на месте использования этого макроса и просто скопируйте себе это в виде функции

Comment: Там вызывается isinf, isinff или isinfl в зависимости от аргумента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать без функции `isinf()`.

Объявляем дополнительную переменную типа `float`, которой присваиваем `inf` или `-inf` путем деления единицы или минус единицы на 0.0 (1/0.0 или -1/0.0).       Точка обязательна!
И затем проверяем наше число с `inf` и `-inf` инструкцией `COMISS`.
Если число равно `inf` или `-inf` флаг `zf` устанавливается в 1.